# how to get the context of a search in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a web page made up of various HTML entities, among them the fragment below:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://example.com/smthg.png" alt="thealtttext" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>My keywords : <a href="http://example.com/hello.html" target="_blank"> some text </a> </strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>some other words : <a href="http://example.com/anotherlink.html" target="_blank"> some other words</a></strong></p>
```

I am interested in the URL after `My keywords` (`http://example.com/hello.html` in the example above). The combination of `My keywords` and the link afterwards is unique in the page.

Right now I use a regex to extract the URL:

```
import requests
import re

def getfile(link):
    r = requests.get(link).text

    try:
        link = re.search('My keyword : <a href="(.+)" target', r).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        print("no direct link for {link}".format(link=link))
    else:
        return link

 print(getfile('http://example.com'))
```

This method, while working, is very dependent on the exact format of the matched string. I would very much prefer to use `BeautifulSoup` to:

- search for `My keyword`
- get its context (by that I mean the whole value of the tag which contains that string, `My keywords : <a href="http://example.com/hello.html" target="_blank"> some text </a>` in the case above)
- run it again though `BeautifulSoup` in order to extract the URL in the `<a>`

I am failing on the second part, I only get

```
[u'My keywords : ']
```

when trying a string search

```
import bs4
import re

thehtml = '''
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://example.com/smthg.png" alt="thealtttext" /></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>My keywords : <a href="http://example.com/hello.html" target="_blank"> some text </a> </strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>some other words : <a href="http://example.com/anotherlink.html" target="_blank"> some other words</a></strong></p>
    '''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(thehtml)
k = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("My keywords"))
print(k)
```

How can I get the whole content of the surrounding tag? (I cannot assume that this will always be `<strong>` as in the example above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find()` instead `find_all()` because there is only one match. Then use `next_sibling` to find the `<a>` tag and `href` to get its value, example:

```
import bs4 
import re

thehtml = ''' 
    <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://example.com/smthg.png" alt="thealtttext" /></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>My keywords : <a href="http://example.com/hello.html" target="_blank"> some text </a> </strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>some other words : <a href="http://example.com/anotherlink.html" target="_blank"> some other words</a></strong></p>
    '''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(thehtml)
k = soup.find(text=re.compile("My keywords")).next_sibling['href']
print(k)
```

yields:

```
http://example.com/hello.html
```

---

**UPDATE**: Based in comments, to get the element that contains some text, use `parent`, like:

```
k = soup.find(text=re.compile("My keywords")).parent.text
```

That yields:

```
<strong>My keywords : <a href="http://example.com/hello.html" target="_blank"> some text </a> </strong>
```